# Typo in Rudin RCA book

Tags: measure-theory

I have some  confusion in Rudin Book page No : $39$

I think  there  is a typo on  page  $39$

My confusion is given below  marked in red circle

[image]

I think    $$g_{s}(x)=\begin{cases}1, & x\in \bar{V_s} \\ s, & x\notin \bar{V_s}. \end{cases} $$ is not correct

**My thinking** :It  should be like  this $$g_{s}(x)=\begin{cases}s, & x\in \bar{V_s} \\ 0, & x\notin \bar{V_s}. \end{cases} $$

Am  i right or wrong ?

Comment: If you read the rest of the proof, especially the last two paragraphs, you will see that Rudin's $g_s$ is the right one.

Comment: i  didn't see   it .can  you write that paragraph @Matematleta